# Fails to import modules installed with conda within a virtual env

Tags: linux, python-3.x, import, module, conda

anaconda3 was installed on linux.

Several modules were installed with conda. They are visible:

```
(cytogen) jeanpat@10TS-Notebook:~$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/jeanpat/anaconda3/envs/cytogen:
#
boost                     1.64.0                   py36_4    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.64.0                        1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.6                         1    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2017.08.26           h1d4fec5_0
```

...

```
graph-tool                2.25             py36hbffa022_0    ostrokach-forge
hdf5                      1.8.17                        2  

mahotas                   1.4.4                    py36_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2018.0.0             hb491cac_4  
mpfr                      3.1.5                         0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.0                  h9df7e31_2  
numpy                     1.12.1           py36he24570b_1  
opencv                    3.1.0               np112py36_1  
opencv3                   3.1.0                    py36_0    menpo
openssl                   1.0.2m               h8cfc7e7_0  
pandas                    0.21.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
pillow                    3.4.2                    py36_0  
pip                       9.0.1            py36h6c6f9ce_4
```

...

```
pytorch                   0.2.0           py36hf0d2509_4cu75    soumith
pytz                      2017.3                     py_2    conda-forge
readline                  7.0                  ha6073c6_4  
scipy                     1.0.0            py36hbf646e7_0  
setuptools                36.5.0           py36he42e2e1_0  
six                       1.11.0                   py36_1    conda-forge
sparsehash                2.0.3                         0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.20.1               hb898158_2  
tk                        8.6.7                hc745277_3  
torchvision               0.1.9            py36h7584368_1    soumith
wheel                     0.29.0           py36he7f4e38_1  
xz                        5.2.3                h55aa19d_2  
zlib                      1.2.11               ha838bed_2
```

When ipython is launched, some modules can't be imported (cv2, mahotas ...):

```
~$ ipython
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import mahotas
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-adadab8066d2> in <module>()
----> 1 import mahotas

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mahotas'

In [2]: import cv2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-72fbbcfe2587> in <module>()
----> 1 import cv2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I guess it is a path issue, for example importing numpy works:

```
In [3]: import numpy

In [4]: numpy.__version__
Out[4]: '1.13.3'
```

but the version doesn't match the numpy version from the virtualenv .

Comment: It is more or less possible to heal the situation by adding paths from within ipython but it's ugly and it fails with cv2 (and work with mahotas). The question is why when creating a virtual env with conda, the paths are not properly set.

Comment: Is ipython installed in the environment?

Comment: yes, ipython was used within the environnment (here called cytogen)

Comment: Just checking that you activated your environment before you launched juptyer notebook? because from the prompt it doesn't look like you did, but maybe you just abbreviated it for clarity.